# How can I get a running crawl(sharepoint) with c#

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am new and know nothing about Sharepoint and Visual Studio and C#.

I need to know how long a crawl is taking. The following code works fine - it's an example from:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc789570.aspx

But it's just the history (like the object CrawlHistory is saying...). To handle problems I need information about the crawl that is running.

I found a enum "CrawlStatus" but I don't know how I can get the crawl.
The crawl starts automatically from MS Sharepoint.

Can anybody help me?

```
...

SearchContext context;
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("myServer"))
    {
         context = SearchContext.GetContext(site);

         CrawlHistory history = new CrawlHistory(context);
         DataTable table = new DataTable();
         table = history.GetCrawlHistory();

...
```

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Search crawling is scheduled as defined in Central Administration. There are two types of crawling Full and Incremental in SharePoint 2010. The first one creates new search index from scratch. The second one makes updates of existing index. Full crawl is needed when updating some search settings. Generally it may take from seconds to hours based on amount of processed data.